# Delete old data from work tables and utilloc

Tags: sas

There's a major space problem on our Windows server.
I want to make sure every morning (or once a week, doesn't matter) before executing scheduled jobs,
one job cleaning the above environment will run first.

Problem is, I can't just delete everything, I want to delete only folders older than 1 day (meaning - yesterday and older)

I thought of using Call System, 
but have no idea how do I delete only the relevant folders.

Ideas anyone?

Thanks alot,
Gal.

Answer (score 0):

I am using FORFILES. This example will delete the files older than 30 days, run it as a .bat file. It takes three arguments, path, days and extension:

```
call :DeleteLogs D:\SAS\Lev1\Logs 30 *
exit /b 0
:DeleteLogs
cd /d %1
FORFILES /D -%2 /M *.%3 /C "cmd /c del /Q @path"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule windows cleanup manager. On 2008 server and later it has to be installed as a feature, you will find it under "Desktop Experience".
In order to create a "task" for the cleanup manager, you can run this command:

```
cleanmgr /sageset:1
```

"1" is the tasknumber, so you can have multiple definitions. Select the stuff you want to delete (I select everything).
You can now run/schedule the task with this command:

```
cleanmgr /sagerun:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
I'm affraid I have no access to the server.
It needs to be done somehow through my pc.

As I mentioned before, I was thinking of Call System,
but no idea how to do that...